# How to generate a random number in vlang?

Tags: vlang

I want to randomly pick an item in a array.Like javascript code

```
words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
```

But I don't know how to generate a number like javascript Math.random() function in vlang. Does anyone know ?

Comment: import rand
println( rand.f64() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation at [rand](https://github.com/vlang/v/tree/master/vlib/rand), you can use the `rand` module and for example, the `rand.u32n(words.length)` function. Make sure you handle the optional case..

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways

- use `choose`

```
import rand
words := ['one', 'two', 'three']
word := rand.choose<string>(words, 1) or {[words[0]]} // this is a list
println(word[0])
```

- use `intn`

```
import rand
words := ['one', 'two', 'three']
word := words[rand.intn(words.len) or {0}]
println(word)
```

Comment: What is the `or {0}` for?

Comment: @McHobbes `intn`  has the possibility of returning an error (if the param is neg) AND `choose` has the possibility of returning an error (if the second param is greater than the array length) so you have to include option to handle those cases (in this case the first element  will be returned in case of error ([code](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/vlib/rand/rand.v))